# Error: No initial system image for this configuration

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-virtual-device

I am trying to build an android emulator image from the source using the guides from https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd.
Here are the commands I run in the order:

```
repo init -u
repo sync -j24
source ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk_phone_x86
make -j32
```

All of these commands succeed and I can see `#### build completed successfully` message. However, when I try to use `emulator` it is displaying following error:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.6.0 (build_id 8095170) (CL:N/A)
ERROR   | No initial system image for this configuration!
```

In addition, when I try to create a zipped image with `make -j32 sdk sdk_repo` command, I can see is that `build-tools` and `platform-tools` are generated however emulator image that is supposed to be in `out/host/darwin-x86/sdk` is missing.

What is the missing point, and how can I build the emulator image in my MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally been able to work this out. I was initially using `master` branch, but then switched to a stable branch via the command:
`repo init -b android-12.0.0_r31`

Secondly, I had to add my MacOS SDK version (12.1) in the following file:

`nano build/soong/cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go`

Finally, I have selected another target as: `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug`.

Then it worked like charm.